# Reading a PNG image in Node.js

Tags: node.js, png

Is there an easy way in Node.js to read a PNG file and get the pixels of the image? Something like [node-image](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-image), but the other way :)

I went through the libraries listed at https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-graphics, but they are either simple wrappers around command line tools providing cropping and resizing or complex drawing tools like `node-canvas`.

Comment: Why wouldn't ``node-canvas`` work for you? Push the png into the canvas and then poke at the pixels in the canvas: http://falcon80.com/HTMLCanvas/PixelManipulation/getImageData.html

Comment: @david-ellis Thank you, I will probably use this, but I wonder if there is a library which does just reading images. Whole canvas with Cairo rendering seems to be a bit overkill.

Comment: It probably wouldn't be too hard of a library to write, but considering how new Node.js is, I doubt such a library exists, yet.

Comment: @DavidEllis [you're wrong](https://github.com/devongovett/png.js)

Comment: Thanks for the info, then, @jmendeth. I did state that I didn't *think* such a library existed. I didn't say I searched for one.

Comment: @honzasp By the way, if you find an answer which solves your problem, please **accept** it by clicking at its **green tick**. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidEllis oh, sorry if I sounded rude. Not my intention at all.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This one does both PNG decoding and encoding without native dependancies:

[pngjs - PNG encoder/decoder for Node.js with no native dependencies.](https://github.com/lukeapage/pngjs)

An example for inverting the colors of a PNG:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
PNG = require('pngjs').PNG;

fs.createReadStream('in.png')
  .pipe(new PNG())
  .on('parsed', function() {

    for (var y = 0; y < this.height; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {
            var idx = (this.width * y + x) << 2;

            // invert color
            this.data[idx] = 255 - this.data[idx]; // R
            this.data[idx+1] = 255 - this.data[idx+1]; // G
            this.data[idx+2] = 255 - this.data[idx+2]; // B

            // and reduce opacity
            this.data[idx+3] = this.data[idx+3] >> 1;
        }
    }

    this.pack().pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.png'));
});
```

Comment: Excuse me, could you have a look at my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46186815/noise-in-png-produced-by-pngjs-for-nodejs ? I'm having trouble with PNG produced by pngjs - it's noisy...

Answer (score 16):

I was about to became mad searching, but I found one:

[**png.js** ― A PNG decoder in JS for the canvas element or Node.js.](https://github.com/devongovett/png.js)

```
var PNG = require('png-js');

var myimage = new PNG('myimage.png');

var width  = myimage.width;
var height = myimage.height;

myimage.decode(function (pixels) {
    //Pixels is a 1D array containing pixel data
});
```

Please note it's *pure* JavaScript. Works both in the **browser** `<canvas>` and in **Node.JS**.

There are more properties apart from `width` and `height`, see [this source](https://github.com/devongovett/png.js/blob/master/png-node.js#L46).

Comment: Oh, this looks great, but when I call PNG.decode, I get a one-dimensional array of pixels (according to the [README](https://github.com/devongovett/png.js/blob/master/README.md), [the code](https://github.com/devongovett/png.js/blob/master/png-node.coffee) and my simple test). Do you know how can I get the width and height? :)

Comment: Yeah, the module is not very well documented. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Aha, thank you, this is close; but I think the PNG constructor expects the actual bytes of the image, so you have to read the file yourself. It may stuck in an infinite loop if you give it bad data, it doesn't even check the PNG header, so be careful with this library!

Comment: Well, the README says you can give it a path or a `Buffer`. In fact, I've been using `new PNG('image.png')` with no problem. But good to know!

Comment: I agree, it should be more robust to avoid infinite loops. You can always `convert` the image to RAW data and manually read that.

Comment: I just tested the source code in the answer above (using the path to an existing image), and I got the following error: `/home/anderson/node_modules/png-js/png-node.js:140
          throw new Error("Incomplete or corrupt PNG file");`. I specified the path to an existing image, so why would this happen?

Comment: I consider this deprecated (at least on Node), use `node-pngjs` instead. It has more features, like encoding and incremental processing. See next answer.

Comment: This library still works fine. It's great for very small simple scripts.

Answer (score 4):

I think

```
var myimage = new PNG('myimage.png');
```

should be

```
var myimage = new PNG.load('myimage.png');
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but the IO action is synchronous. I think the best way is `fs.readFile (err, data) -> image = new PNG(data)`.