# Get an array of pixels from an image file using node.js

Tags: image, node.js

Is it possible to get an array of RGB values from a local image file using node.js? I'm trying to write a script that takes a file path as its parameter and returns an array that represents the pixel data.

```
function getPixelArray(filePath){
    //return an array of RGB values that correspond to the image
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247790/reading-a-png-image-in-node-js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your image is in PNG format, have a look at https://github.com/devongovett/png.js/

Comment: Is it also possible to save the pixel data as a file (using some other node.js library)? I'd like to modify the array of pixel data, and then  save it as a png image again.

Comment: Also, is there any way to obtain the image width and height using png-js?

Comment: how about without a library?

Answer (score 29):

You can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp
This could be useful:

```
Jimp.read("http://www.example.com/path/to/lenna.jpg", function (err, image) {
    image.getPixelColor(x, y); // returns the colour of that pixel e.g. 0xFFFFFFFF
});
```

To get RGB you can use:

```
Jimp.intToRGBA(hex); // e.g. converts 0xFFFFFFFF to {r: 255, g: 255, b: 255, a:255}
```

Comment: *And use **`image.bitmap.data`** to get a **Buffer of the raw bitmap data**.*