# How to get pixels data of image?

Tags: node.js

I want to manipulate an image with pure NodeJS

I can't find a way how to get the pixel data of an image. I can get the buffer and base64 of the image. I found many libraries that provide this functionality, but I can't reproduce it myself. I thought this was easy to do because in JavaScript we have a Canvas which gives any information about an image and is easy to manipulate

Here is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('cat.png', (e,image) => {
  console.log(image.toString('base64'));
})
```

May be here is another way how to read the image?

If this is not possible with pure Node JS, could you please explain to me:

1. Why?
2. How do other libraries work with images?

Comment: what do you mean you've found "other libraries"? in npm? if they don't have external software dependencies is has to be achievable by "pure NodeJS". like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41460508/4935162). Granted, the source code is 20K lines.

Comment: I found `sharp`, `jimp`, `png.js` and so on. But can't figure out how they work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get an array of pixels from an image file using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286039/get-an-array-of-pixels-from-an-image-file-using-node-js)

Comment: @Peterrabbit They used libraries and there is answer to any of my questions

Comment: From a quick overview it seems png.js is by far the simplest. Head over to its [source code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/png-js?activeTab=explore), click on `png-node.js` and check out the `decode` function.

Comment: You can do this with pure nodejs but it will be a big amount of complicated code. Libraries like jimp will offer you features similar to what the canvas api does in a browser but coding this yourself makes no sense, except for learning maybe but it's not easy at all.