# Noise in PNG produced by pngjs for nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, png

I want to slice PNG spritesheet to sprites using [pngjs](https://github.com/lukeapage/pngjs) v3.3.0 for nodejs. This gives me unxpected noisy background for some of produced sprites. Then I tryed simple script that just creates empty transparent PNG and then writes it to a file:

```
var fs          = require('fs');
var PNG         = require('pngjs').PNG;
var dstBuffer   = new PNG({ width:50, height:50 });

dstBuffer.pack().pipe(fs.createWriteStream("empty.png"));
```

And empty PNG is created with noisy background as well. I also tried to not to use transparency (colorType:2), then I got white PNG with noise on it. And every time I use the script, noise differs. [This is how it looks like](https://i.gyazo.com/177cd9d1445a2b33e7932394dfcfdade.png). Tried sync and async approach.

I run sccript simply in cmd as follows: `node pngjs`. And pngjs installed just with npm: `npm install pngjs`. So I need to avoid this noise on background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data needs to be initialized. This can be achieved like this (also see https://github.com/lukeapage/pngjs/blob/master/examples/newfile.js):

```
var fs          = require('fs');
var PNG         = require('pngjs').PNG;
var dstBuffer   = new PNG({ width:50, height:50 });

for (var y = 0; y < dstBuffer.height; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < dstBuffer.width; x++) {
        var idx = (dstBuffer.width * y + x) << 2;

        dstBuffer.data[idx] = 255;
        dstBuffer.data[idx + 1] = 255;
        dstBuffer.data[idx + 2] = 255;

        dstBuffer.data[idx + 3] = 255;
    }
}

dstBuffer.pack().pipe(fs.createWriteStream("empty.png"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how to preserve transparent bg in this case?

Comment: Found myself that need to use dstBuffer.data[idx + 3] = 0; for that. Thanks you!